# Вызвать событие click() без клика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается в скрипте вызвать событие click без фактического клика.

Суть в том, что у меня в модальном окне открываются табы, а по нажатию по табам в них подгружается информация. Так вот чтобы для первого таба информация подгрузилась сразу после открытия нужно вызвать функцию click для элемента с классом current

не работает....

```
$('.fabric-tabs .tab-link.current').click();
```

Comment: Как понимаю, не срабатывает, потому что класса current нет? При открытии модалки просто вызывайте функцию (а не клик на элемент), которая подгрузит инфу в первый таб.

Comment: @Crasher думаю годится как ответ

Comment: @Crasher, класс есть

Comment: @Batyabest, тогда код в студию. Так сложно понять, что, где и как происходит

Comment: @Crasher, прописал просто функцию, как вы и говорил - все работает, Спасибо